# Trouble Setting Up Skeleton Angular Application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, crud, mean-stack

I keep getting this error while trying to set up this skeleton application. I have no idea how to fix it sadly. Any input would be much appreciated. I'm just trying to get the darn thing up.

```
C:\Users\x\Desktop\mean-stripdown-master>node server
Express app started on port 3000

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x\Desktop\mean-stripdown-master\node_modul
es\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:540:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x\Desktop\mean-stripdown-master\node_modul
es\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:140:1
5)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x\Desktop\mean-stripdown-master\node_mod
ules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:478:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details about the skeleton. The stack trace provided shows that it is `mongodb connection` related error while running app on node server. Where angularjs comes into picture?

Comment: It def looks like you don't have mongo properly installed and configured.

Comment: Resolved. YOu were right Vijay in that I was stupid and forgot to disconnect MongoDB.